# Saving Modified XML- WP8 C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I've been trying to modify and save an xml dynamically. i've tried to find some answers but i didnt manage to.
i Succeeded to modify and change the xml data, but i encounter a problem with saving. 
here is the code:

```
var resourceStreamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
using (var stream = resourceStreamInfo.Stream)
{
     doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
     var Currencies = doc.Descendants("Currency");
     XElement root = Currencies.Where(b => b.Element("ID").Value.IndexOf(CurrencyID, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).First();
     root.SetElementValue("Rate", rate);

     doc.Save(stream);
}
```

I understood that my stream is readonly, but what should I do?

Comment: Where's the XML located? I'd gladly modify HTML on the whitehouse.gov this way, if it were possible :)

Comment: the xml is in the Solution File :P

Answer (score 0):

From `Application.GetResourceStream`I guess your are reading a file from your project bundle. You cannot modify it. You need to save the modified file to isolated storage

Comment: i'm not sure do you mean by that. do you mean: xml serialization? can you give me a question with this answer? THX